# Cannot found any data type used by SendInput() function

Tags: c, winapi, sendinput

I'm trying to use `SendInput()` function. I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

//...

    KEYBDINPUT kbi;
    kbi.wVk = 0x31;
    kbi.wScan = 0;
    kbi.dwFlags = 0;
    kbi.time = 0;

    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input.ki = kbi;

    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof input);
```

Compiling:

`gcc -Wall -o window.exe win32.c -lWs2_32`

I get:

```
win32.c: In function ‘main’:
win32.c:13:2: error: ‘KEYBDINPUT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
win32.c:13:2: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
win32.c:13:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘kbi’
win32.c:14:2: error: ‘kbi’ undeclared (first use in this function)
win32.c:20:2: error: ‘INPUT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
win32.c:20:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘input’
win32.c:21:2: error: ‘input’ undeclared (first use in this function)
win32.c:21:15: error: ‘INPUT_KEYBOARD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I have no idea how to fix tihis. According the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it's declared in `Winuser.h` header. But don't works for me.

Comment: You can check the header files if those structures have been declared under some macro, in which case you will have to pass that macro definition through command line using `-D` option or explicitly define it in your source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0403
#include <windows.h>
```

Seems this is the magic #define you need somewhere in your project (either explicitly in code, or via compiler command line param -D).

Note that windows.h includes winuser.h, so there's no need to include that, as it's included already for you. Also, the WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN define only has any effect if it's included *before* windows. Details about what it does [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/30/9929944.aspx); it's not needed or particularly useful these days.

--

So what's going on here? Looking for the definition of KBDINPUT in winuser.h (C:\Cygwin\usr\include\w32api\winuser.h), we see:

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0403)
typedef struct tagMOUSEINPUT {
...
} MOUSEINPUT,*PMOUSEINPUT;
typedef struct tagKEYBDINPUT {
...
```

That's the problem; these only get defined if _WIN32_WINNT is greater than 0x0403.

Those are the files from the cygwin package. Interestingly, the winuser.h from the Microsoft SDK (usually installed in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include\WinUser.h) uses a different condition:

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT > 0x0400)
```

...which explains Jay's suggestion - he's likely looking at the MS files, where 0x0401 would be sufficient here; and also explains why it's not working for you - you're likely using the cygwin ones with a higher version requirement. As to why these two files are different - I've no idea there...

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to add

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0401
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
```

before including windowsh and winuser.h in your source.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with older IDEs like VC6, I tried the above and it didn't work. I had to supply the flag on project settings.

Go to Setting >> C/C++ tab >> select 'General' from Catagory combo box
add `/D _WIN32_WINNT=0x401` to Project settings edit box. That's for VC6.

[/d](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235412(v=vs.60).aspx) is how you supply the flag and the actual flag is _WIN32_WINNT=0x401. I do had to set it to 0x401, other values like 0x0500 were causing more errors.